# Vagrant, Composer, and a Proxy

Tags: vagrant, composer-php

I am trying to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) on a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) instance while behind an HTTP proxy. Composer seems to require 'http_proxy' environment variable to be set in a previous session before it will see it. Once it sees it, there is no problem. So if I run 'vagrant up' on a new instance, the provisioning will fail. If I run 'vagrant provision' immediately after, it will succeed. Is there a way to make composer work successfully the first time? I tried using two separate provisioning scripts, but that yielded the same results. I've dabbled with setsid to no avail, but I'm not very familiar with it so possible I was using it incorrectly.

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh", :privileged => false
end
```

**provision.sh**

```
echo "********** Configuring for HTTP Proxy **********"
http_proxy=<insert proxy value here>
echo "HTTP Proxy = " $http_proxy
# Set proxy for apt-get
echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"$http_proxy\";" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null
# Set proxy for wget
echo "https_proxy = $http_proxy" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc > /dev/null
echo "http_proxy = $http_proxy" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc > /dev/null
# Set proxy for shell
echo http_proxy="$http_proxy" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment > /dev/null

sudo apt-get -q -y update
sudo apt-get install -qq -y php5-cli php5-curl

sudo wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/composer https://getcomposer.org/download/1.0.0-alpha8/composer.phar
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
wget -q -O /tmp/drush.tar.gz https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/archive/6.4.0.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/drush
sudo chown -R vagrant: /opt/drush
tar xzf /tmp/drush.tar.gz --strip 1 -C /opt/drush
cd /opt/drush
composer install
sudo ln -s /opt/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Comment: Check out the [vagrant-proxyconf](http://tmatilai.github.io/vagrant-proxyconf/) plugin for setting the proxy configuration for the whole VM. </shameless_plug>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install of having http_proxy=, it needed to have export http_proxy=